# how to filter log data which specify column is bigger than a value

Tags: linux, awk, sed

need to check logs, logs format as below, normally I get logs by `cat ***.log | grep --color -a 'keywords'`I wanna get all logs which `proctm` > 30000µs, anyone knows how to write linux command? thank u

```
traceid=1f8a1b84c113b31e2fd6589cbf339600|***|errcode=0|proctm=28887µs|usetrx= false|ormstats=0 0 0|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. We could do this in a single `awk` itself.

```
awk '
/keyword/ && match($0,/proctm=[^µ]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",val)
  if(val+0>30000){ print }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
/keyword/ && match($0,/proctm=[^µ]*/){         ##Using match function to match regex proctm= till µ here.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)   ##Creating val which has sub string which has matched regex value.
  sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",val)           ##Substituting everything apart from digit in val.
  if(val+0>30000){ print }        ##Checking if val is greater than 30000 then print current line.
}
'  Input_file                     ##Mention *.log to pass all log files here.
```

Comment: never used awk, let me learn and test first

Comment: @Frank, sure you could see this link also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info for more details and learning, cheers.

Comment: it doesn't work, still can get records which `proctm` < 30000. I copied ur above and replaced `Input_file` name

Comment: @Frank, for shown simple test line it has worked fine for me, could you please post a sample line for which it didn't work for you?

Comment: okay I gave 2 samples below `sample log` in my question as it's too long to add in this comment, u can check that

Comment: @Frank, I have edited my code now, could you please do check it once and let me know if All is Well now.

Comment: it works, by the way, if I wanna add some other `grep keyword` limit rules, how should I do? for example, I wanna get `proctm>3000` and contains `XXXProcessor ` logs

Comment: @Frank, I have added additional condition `/keyword/` in it change `keyword` with your actual searchable string and then try it out, let me know how it goes cheers

Comment: it works, if I wanna add 2 more keywords for filtering, just using `&`?

Comment: @Frank, sure change `/keyword/ && match($0,/proctm=[^µ]*/)` TO `/keyword1/ && /keyword2/ && match($0,/proctm=[^µ]*/)` in above code, cheers.

Comment: hi sorry do u know how to exact match keyword for above, I found `/keyword/` means contains, thank u

Comment: @Frank, if you know the field number, then you could do `$1=="keyword"` which means to check if 1st column is keyword.

Comment: sorry I'm new for awk, for example, I wanna match `errcode`  for above sample log, which number shoud?

Comment: @Frank, `traceid=1f8a1b84c113b31e2fd6589cbf339600|***|errcode=0|proctm=28887µs|usetrx= false|ormstats=0 0 0|` for this line to PRINT your field numbers use: `awk -F'|' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print "Field number is:"i" field value is:" $i}}' file` it will show you the field number which you can use for printing the respective field.

Comment: tried but failed, I got `ERROR` number is 2 for `2021-04-29 14:23:15.815391|ERROR|1f8a1b84c11687c472f6c31d29148400|client.go:75|httpClient.Do|method=POST,endpoint=`, and I used `awk '
$2=="ERROR" && match($0,/proctm=[^µ]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",val)
  if(val+0>30000){ print }
}
'  Input_file`  it doesn't work, can help to check?

Comment: @Frank. Could you please post sample line on which you are running above command.

Comment: actually already sent u, `2021-04-29 14:23:15.815391|ERROR|1f8a1b84c11687c472f6c31d29148400|client.go:75|httpClient.Do|method=POST,endpoint=`, wanna find all this `ERROR`

Comment: @Frank, I can't see µ here may that's the reason its failing

Comment: oh sorry forgot it, let me change

Comment: hi  I wanna match `ERROR` and print,  `awk -F : '$2=="ERROR" {print $0}' file` for above, is that correct? seems doesn't work

Comment: @Frank, In my humble opinion, I would like to request you to open a new question, since question in this post was totally different and your new questions are little different(which may confuse future readers/users), so would like to request you to open a new question with your efforts/code and we can discuss there(please don't forget to attach your code and samples in new post), cheers.